# Does an antimagic field remain after the caster dies/goes unconscious?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

If I kill or knock unconscious somebody who has cast an [antimagic field](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/antimagicField.html), does it stay in effect, following his body? I gather from [this RPG SE answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/36877/13529) that durational spells don't automatically end when their caster dies, and I would assume that also applies to AMF, but I'd like to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Unless a spell has "Duration: Concentration, or Duration: Instantaneous" a spell's effect will not vanish unless dispelled or until it durates regularly, even if the caster is killed or knocked unconscious.

Comment: Duration:Instantaneous?  That seems misleading; people might think you mean a Fireball's effects (damage+being on fire) end when its caster dies.  (this is wrong)