# Do Permanent Spells Remain after a Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, polymorph

I'm playing a wizard and I've cast Permanency on Tongues and Arcane Sight. If I Polymorph myself into a Sun Giant, do those spells remain active?

Furthermore, if I cast Haste earlier in the round, does the Haste spell still apply if I cast Polymorph afterwards?

Comment: See this question here (relates to Pathfinder, so probably still valid): http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/36876/what-happens-to-spells-buffs-curses-ect-that-are-active-on-you-when-you-die

Comment: @abza Pathfinder substantially changes the polymorph rules, so it's not actually a safe bet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, spells remain for their duration unless otherwise stated they are dispelled, cancelled or surpressed.

This is inferred by the [Main FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616150335/http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/files/Main35FAQv06302008.zip) that even casting a spell that depends on type would remain when polymorphed.  I recall a similar FAQ question for Enlarge Person but stopped digging when I found this.

> *If, while under the effect of a spell that depends on type (such as hold person), my character is transformed into a different creature type by polymorph, does the spell’s effect remain?*
>
> Yes. A spell only checks to see if you are a legal target when it is cast. If you become an illegal target later (such as via the polymorph spell), the spell remains in effect.
>
> *The question and answer uses “polymorph” to refer specifically to spells that rely on the polymorph or alter self spell to adjudicate their effect (including alter self, polymorph, polymorph any object, and shapechange), psionic powers based on the metamorphosis power (including metamorphosis and greater metamorphosis), and any other effect based on either of these lists.

Comment: Note that the /effect/ of spells on unexpected targets is still somewhat case-by-case. For example: disguise self as an elf guard then polymorph to an owlbear: disguise self will keep running its duration out, but may not have any effect while you are owlbearing about.

Comment: @fectin I find that use of the verb *to owlbear* completely unowlbearable.

Answer (score -1):

### YES, because that depends on...

As long as the effect of the spell is not specifically thwarted by changing into the new (creature-)type and form it remains in effect. Instantaneous effects always persist. Personal spell-effects are never actually dispelled by polymorphing AFAIK, just temporarily suppressed.

For example, if the new shape has eyes, *arcane sight* would remain in effect. If the new shape has no abilities for verbal communication, *tongues* would no longer have any effect, although it is NOT dispelled and will work again as soon as you change in a creature that has ways of verbally communicating. A Sun Giant would lose none of the mentioned effects, for it has the means (eyes+mouth) to use them.