# Can one wildshape to escape from the Hold Person spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, wild-shape

A person who is subjected to the Hold Person spell, presuming they fail their save, is paralyzed. This means they can only take purely mental actions.
Furthermore, the target of Hold Person must be humanoid.

As far as I am aware, Wildshaping is a purely mental action. Though I am not actually certain if this is the case.
Would it be possible to wildshape into an animal while under the effect of Hold Person? And if yes, would the fact that you are no longer a suitable target mean that the spell is supressed- Even though it has already affected you?

Comment: RE: "And if yes, would the fact that you are no longer a suitable target mean that the spell is supressed- Even though it has already affected you?" I know it might not seem like it, but that is a deeply controversial question and should be asked separately. Quite a few other questions address the issue of after-the-fact target-checking, though. I suggest doing a thorough search.

Comment: I did some searching for you. Try [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142271/8610), [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84109/8610), and especially [here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79356/8610)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Wild Shape won't help

This is because this ability doesn't change your type. It functions like Alternate Form, and Alternate Form states

> The creature retains the type and subtype of its original form.

#### For other abilities, ask your DM

There is a thing called constant targetting (check [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79356/do-non-instantaneous-spells-fail-if-the-target-becomes-illegal-later-on-in-the-s) and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142271/what-happens-if-a-druid-uses-share-spells-to-share-a-spell-that-blocks-extraordi), with thanks to @HeyICanChan for his search). In short, it is not entirely clear if d&d 3.5 uses it or not. So, it is unclear if effects check if target is valid... each turn? Each action? They clearly check when they are applied, but after that it may be played both ways.

---

*Note:* I may say, I would allow someone using Still Silent Polymorph to escape Hold Person via it. But its just me. On the other hand, Main D&D FAQ (which is sometimes [approached with skepticism](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60044/what-is-wrong-with-the-dd-3-5-faq)), for example, disagrees, containing the following exchange

> **Q: If, while under the effect of a spell that depends on type (such as hold person), my character is transformed into a different creature type by polymorph, does the spell’s effect remain?**
>   A: Yes. A spell only checks to see if you are a legal target when it is cast. If you become an illegal target later (such as via the polymorph spell), the spell remains in effect.