# How can I reliably increase our giant ape's AC to 16 (or better)?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph, armor-class

A tactical problem to solve based on last night's session

### Tactical Situation

1. Wizard polymorphs warlock (8th level) into a Giant Ape. (Did T-Rex last time, looking for variety and higher INT (7 vs 2); we also like that Giant Ape has a ranged option, throwing rocks, which the T-Rex does not).
2. Giant ape engages with a platoon of hobgoblin cavalry (11 hobgoblins on 11 worgs, wizard refrains from using fireball for in-story reasons)
3. In two rounds, partly due to martial advantage, the AC 12 Giant Ape takes 87 damage (out of 157) while only engaging three or four of the enemy (the Barbarian and Fighter were also engaged and the "quantity has a quality all its own" phenomenon of 5e was in evidence)
4. Fight ended when bard (hidden) cast *Wall of Thorns* from his Anstruth Harp which broke up the hobgoblin formation considerably.

#### Problem: Giant Ape's HP melted down too quickly due to low AC

The AC of 12 didn't do much to stop hits from landing; we anticipate much tougher foes than Hobgoblins in the near future. (Party is made up of level 8 PCs). We are kicking around a solution that goes something like this:

1. Warlock is polymorphed into Giant Ape
2. Someone casts barkskin on Warlock, sets AC to 16

   > Duration: Concentration, up to 1 hour
   > You touch a willing creature.  Until the spell ends, the target’s skin has a rough, bark-like appearance, and the target’s AC can’t be less than 16, regardless of what kind of armor it is wearing.

We believe that if we cast *barkskin* on the Warlock before the *polymorph*, the 16 AC would not carry over. (If we have that wrong, please explain why).

#### What we seek in an answer

Presuming that we have three eligible spell casters - Arcane Trickster, Bard(Valor), and Wizard(Evoker); warlock is the party's go to for being turned into creatures) - how do I get one of them *Barkskin* to cast onto her?  {It's a druid/ranger spell, and the Anstruth Harp doesn't have the spell on it the way the MacFuirmidh Cittern does}.

#### Another good kind of answer

If there is a different way to boost the Giant Ape's AC, that's also a good answer.

Note: the group of players, as a whole, really enjoyed having King Kong (well, Queen Kong) mix it up during the fight.  Assume for any answer that we will use the Giant Ape again, not a T Rex or other beast, since it was a very popular choice once we all did the after battle confab.

Answer (score 26):

### Any spell that can boost armor will work.

There's no real problem with casting *barkskin* or *mage armor* prior to transforming; the spell effect will carry over after you transform. Polymorph doesn't block any ongoing spell effects. While your statistics get replaced by the creature's, spell effects aren't *your* statistics, they're the effects of a magic spell and consequently carry over to your new form.

This is explicitly covered in the Sage Advice Compendium:

> **Can a creature under the effects of *polymorph* have other spell effects on them, or are those game statistics also replaced by those of the beast form?**
>
> *Polymorph* replaces only the target's character sheet or stat block with the stat block of the chosen form. Other effects, such as other spells, still exist.

So the easiest thing is probably *mage armor* (or in your case, the *armor of shadows* invocation), which should get your Giant Ape form up to AC 15, which is *nearly* your target. I don't know of a good way to get *barkskin* with the group you're with, but I think there's an easier answer on your own invocation list.

Alternatively, another player could cast *mage armor* on you -- it used to be "self only" in prior editions, but these days it can be delivered by touch. You may need to be a little thoughtful about how your gear is set up, though -- if you were wearing armor in your human form and then polymorphed into an ape, your ape form would be a valid target for *mage armor* but the spell would end as soon as you reverted because you'd then be wearing physical armor, which breaks the spell.

Comment: How do I support that point in paragraph 1?  My DM sometimes needs stuff explained in more detail.  My instinct is "makes sense" but he sometimes takes more convincing. What you are telling me is that if the barbarian is hasted (by our bard) the Wizard can turn him into a hasted King Kong?

Comment: Yes, you'd be a Hasty Kong. I added a direct quote from the Sage Advice Compendium. I hope that covers it.

Comment: Hasted Raging Kong with an Insignia of Claws and some Ring/Cloak of Protection. What a sight to behold.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reference. *Why didn't I look at sage advice?*  got it. @BlueMoon93 muahahahah, now that would be nusto fun. 

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Might be worth noting that you'd have to take the Insignia of Claws and (Item) of Protection off before turning into an ape. Polymorph merges items into your form regardless of if your new form can use them.

Comment: @InternetHobo Ah, true, i was mixing things with Wild Shape

Comment: Also note, if the party Wizard knows Mage Armor and can spare a lvl1 spell slot, *Mage Armor can be cast on other people*.  (Range: Touch.  Duration: 8h.  Not concentration).  And no limit on number of targets you have it active on, so they could buff themselves with it as well, making it more worth preparing every day.  That would free up @KorvinStarmast's Warlock invocations and/or known spells + spell slots for other fun stuff, if you can count on your wizard ally for Mage Armor.  I'd suggest pointing that out in this answer, that it's applicable now (or upon spell book update, not lvl up)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm, that might be a best case approach.

Answer (score 7):

### What you can do now

#### Magical Armor

As others have suggested, AC enhancement spells like *mage armor* and *barkskin* will remain in effect even after you are *polymorphed* (although for mage armor the AC will be based on the ape's dexterity).

[From Sage Advice](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf):

> **Can a creature under the effects of polymorph have other spell effects on them, or are those game statistics also replaced by the those of the beast form?** Polymorph replaces only the target’s character sheet or stat block with the stat block of the chosen form. Other effects, such as other spells, still exist.

See also: [Can polymorph end spells that require the target to be humanoid?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103845/can-polymorph-end-spells-that-require-the-target-to-be-humanoid)

These may be cast before *or* after the *polymorph*, and if they were already in effect on the warlock they will be retained.

#### Dodge

Have the ape engage, and then take the dodge action.  While at disadvantage to be hit, the ape's armor class is roughly equivalent to 17, and it still gets to make one opportunity attack on any opponents that leave its reach.  This does limit your offensive capability, but allows the ape to distract and pin down the enemy while the rest of the party is executing their actions.

#### Consider other forms

The [huge giant crab](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/adventures/storm-lords-wrath#HugeGiantCrab) has better hp than the ape and AC15.  As CR8 it should be available to your Level 8 warlock.  However, only one attack, no missile attacks, and terrible Int score of 1 (even worse than the *T. rex*).

Ask your DM about [animals off the books](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177998/checking-cr-calculation-for-homebrew-larger-version-of-giant-ape).  If your DM is open to the wizard making up fantastic beasts based on rumors rather than experience, ask to work with them on a CR8 form that has a better AC than the giant ape.

### For the Future

#### Shadow of Moil

When your Warlock hits ninth and can add / switch spells, she could add *Shadow of Moil* from [XGtE](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/xanathars-guide-to-everything).

> Flame-like shadows wreathe your body until the spell ends, causing you to become heavily obscured to others. The shadows turn dim light within 10 feet of you into darkness, and bright light in the same area to dim light.  Until the spell ends, you have resistance to radiant damage. In addition, whenever a creature within 10 feet of you hits you with an attack, the shadows lash out at that creature, dealing it 2d8 necrotic damage.

With a duration of one minute, this would have to be cast on herself just before she was *polymorphed*.  However, once in place you can use the ape's low AC and high hp to great effect to winnow lots of chaff.  In effect, you want the ape to be hit to get multiple necrotic attacks per round.

Unfortunately it would use the warlock's Concentration and would thus be vulnerable to going down on each hit, but with the ape she would at least have a +4 Con save bonus.

This would also stack with other armor solutions (*mage armor*, *barkskin*), including her own *armor of shadows* if she swapped that back in at 9th.

Comment: Warlock has war caster and resilient CON: the Shadows of Moil is a neat idea.  Lemme think that one over

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Unfortunately, feats wouldn't be kept in ape form either.  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141776/can-i-benefit-from-a-feat-effect-while-polymorphed.  However, it might be worth asking the DM that if concentration can be maintained while polymorphed, shouldn't feats that affect concentration apply?  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59071/does-whether-a-wizard-can-maintain-the-spell-polymorph-upon-themselves-depend-on

Comment: @Kirt while I do not agree with rubik's answer, that's a fair way to rule it

Comment: @KorvinStarmast  Worth a conversation with your DM.  If they rule you can retain feats, it seems you are already heavily invested in maintaining concentration, making _Shadows of Moil_ a better choice.  You might consider _sculptor of flesh_ and have the warlock polymorph herself as well, meaning the wizard could then give her concentration buffs.

Comment: @Kirt that's a neat idea, now that I have warcaster.  Before, we determined that the conc would drop too often as she'd get hit too often.  Now that I have the chance for advantage on con saves, we can reconsider, so that's a great point! +1 your comment!  

Comment: Note that giving enemies disadvantage (e.g. via Dodge) works *much* better when your base AC is higher.  You want only the tail of the probability distribution to beat your AC, not still getting hit by their most likely range of rolls.  For an opponent with a +2 to hit against AC 12 (so they need a 10 or higher on the die), yes disadvantage is about the same as +5 AC.  If they have a +8 to hit you, (need a 4 or higher on the die), disadvantage is only about equivalent to +3 AC.  (DC4 row of the table on https://www.reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/2sq49q/table_of_probabilities_for_advantage_and/)

Comment: The (lack of) benefit to dodging with low AC is more obvious in absolute terms: if someone needs a 4 to hit you, they'll hit 85% of the time.  Imposing disadvantage means they'll still hit you ~72.3% of the time.  So you've spent your action to prevent ~15% of the expected-average number of hits this round.  vs. if they need a 10 to hit you, base chance is 55%, disadvantage chance is 30.3%.  So you're preventing ~45% of the hits on average.  Things get rapidly better with even higher AC, e.g. needing 15 is 30% vs. 9% chance to be hit; you avoid more than 2/3rd of the hits you would have taken

Comment: So if you can boost your AC even a little bit above 12, that makes dodging as well *much* more effective against crowds of weak monsters with bonuses like +2 or +3 (hobgoblin), while your allies thin the crowd some.  Doing stuff to prevent enemy advantage is also less valuable when your AC is really low compared to their +hit, they'd probably hit anyway.  But still, it can make sense if there are enough small enemies; dodging could help more in the short term than using your action to kill one.

Answer (score 5):

For wild shape you can get an ioun stone and/or animated shield. Standard animated shield is just +2AC and ioun stone +1, but there is no reason +1-+3 animated shields or ioun stones can't exist. In the game I'm running the druid has a +1 animated shield for +3AC. Unfortunately in your case thoguh polymorph is worded so this won't work.

Barkskin should carry over though. Stats are replaced with the apes, but active spells don't go away as far as I know. So I think barkskin should keep functioning. Instead of a human or whatever race he is with barkskin, he becomes an ape with barkskin. That's part of what makes moon druids good, they can shape change as a bonus action, so they can cast a spell then shape change first round, and the spell effect stays on (like call lightning). So they can rain lightning bolts down on the enemy while having a bunch of temporary HP. If this works I don't see why barkskin wouldn't. This question is for wildshape but the same reasoning should apply to polymorph:

[Does Barkskin cast before Wild Shaping apply to your beast form?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/63352/does-barkskin-cast-before-wild-shaping-apply-to-your-beast-form)

Comment: We are not using wild shape, druid feature, we are using polymorph, the 4th level spell.  I'd need more support to show that AC remains 16. (But if that's true, great)

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84109/do-permanent-spells-remain-after-a-polymorph#:~:text=Yes%2C%20spells%20remain%20for%20their,are%20dispelled%2C%20cancelled%20or%20surpressed.&text=A%20spell%20only%20checks%20to,the%20spell%20remains%20in%20effect.

Comment: Wrong edition, that's for 3.5

Comment: @KorvinStarmast The spell as you've quoted doesn't say anything about it ending on polymorph. Only concentration and 1 hour being limits. So unless polymorph says that it would end ongoing magical effects I think the question would be why do you think that barkskin wouldn't last? I can certainly see the narrative argument that the bark is lost with the shape change but that isn't supported by the rules as far as I am aware.

Comment: updated my answer with a link to an example and with game developers saying it works that way for wild shape and why. Their reasoning would apply equally to polymorph.

Comment: @AndrewADeMarco Not sure why you say that; they are subtly different, like in the mental stats being the same and if you are a druid monk the AC being calculated like a Monk's ... though it seems logical from the broader perspective.

Comment: Hmm, Ioun Stone. When we get to the capital city, that might be worth trading for but it's only a +1

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: An Ioun Stone requires attunement, so you couldn't keep it separate from polymorph and then have the Ape attune it within polymorph duration.  Wild Shape gives the druid the option of having their gear worn by their new form (and functioning), different from polymorph where the only choice is to merge and have it non-functioning.  https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167 *You choose whether your equipment falls to the ground in your space, merges into your new form, or is worn by it.*  This part of the answer only applies to Wild Shape, not Poly :/.

Comment: ok, I will remove the first part, since that means animated shield is out too, as that requires attunment, didn't know that was a wild shape specific thing

Comment: @PeterCordes ah, yes, melds into the polymorph form

Comment: @AndrewADeMarco: Indeed, a recent Q&A which also made it to Hot Network Questions hinged on the implications of that and thus discussed it in some detail: [Does Polymorph break attunements with prerequisites?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/184372) (it's possible to read RAW in a way that implies yes, but the "no" position is fortunately also compatible with RAW, it all depends on rules lawyering, or a decision that it would be silly for it to work that way :P.)

Comment: Still, you might want to re-add that section to your answer but make it clear that it only applies to Wild Shaped Giant Apes, as opposed to Polyed.  Could be useful for future readers who get here based on the title, and are still looking for ideas that work for their variation on the question.  (Unless there's already another Q&A about AC boosts for Wild Shaped druids, in which case it should get linked in a comment, or note in the question.)

Answer (score 5):

Ok, hear me out. Magic armors +1, +2, +3 don't require attunement.

Additionally, per the DMG in the "Wearing and wielding items" page 140:

> In most cases, a magic item that's meant to be worn can fit a creature regardless of size or build.

I know "most cases" is vague on purpose, but assuming polymorph lasts one hour, and it takes 10 minutes to don heavy armor, a giant ape could don a magic chain mail, splint, or plate armor for 21 AC max if it's a +3 Plate.

I feel a DM might not allow these shenanigans, specially since an ape is not a humanoid. But if Hill Giants can wear armor, it's not a stretch for a big monkey to do so. If this was some sort of Kong vs. Godzilla situation, as a DM I would allow it.

Comment: Doesn't the line "The creature can't activate, use, wield, or otherwise benefit from any of its Equipment." mean you can't use any equipment while polymorphed?

Comment: @AllanMills Yeah, they'd need to have Giant Ape-sized armor stored away for them to put on after they transformed.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I suspect our DM would raise and eyebrow and say "no, from medium to Huge is too much of a reach"

Comment: The warlock almost certainly doesn't have heavy armor proficiency.  The ape is even less likely to.

Comment: @BenBarden she has +1 studded leather

Comment: So, does the armor proficiency transfer?  I'm not convinced that it does.

Comment: @Ben My guess is no

Answer (score 3):

### College of Valor, *Combat Inspiration* may boost AC enough

At the party's level, 8, the Valor Bard has 4 or 5 Bardic Inspiration uses per short rest. (Charisma of 18 or 20 assumed<sup>1</sup>).  While this won't stop critical hits, and neither will an AC of 16, rolling a d8 as a reaction to an attack will improve the Armor Class by an average of 4.5 for some of the attacks made against the Giant Ape.  In those cases, the AC will range from 13 - 20 based on the Ape's Dexterity of 14 (+2 to AC) and the die roll.
**Combat Inspiration**

> ... when an attack roll is made against the creature, it can use its reaction to roll the Bardic Inspiration Die and add ithe number rolled to its AC against one attack after seeing the roll but before knowing if it hits or misses" (PHB, College of Valor)

#### Costs, Benefits, and Reliability

1. Costs:  this approach has its {opportunity} costs .  There is no free lunch.

   - Dedicating this party resource to boosting the Ape's
     chance to-not-be-hit costs the chance of another party member
     getting a hit, succeeding on an ability check, or making a saving
     throw with a Bardic Inspiration roll on the d8.  The party needs to assess how often and how well they use Bardic Inspiration in general - since it recharges on each short rest this could be used to avoid taking damage via boosted AC about a dozen times per adventuring day, depending on how many short rests happen in a given adventure day.
   - This approach puts a burden on the bard *player* to be alert to this requirement for some combats (when Queen Kong is present) and not others, and to more carefully manage and apply Bardic Inspiration than he does now. (Yes, I am in the group, and I am self-answering). In a party where the Bard player is very pro-active, this is not such a burden.
   - If the Giant Ape uses a reaction to avoid a hit, that reaction during that round can't be used for an opportunity attack (if, for example, bard casts *fear* or *dissonant whispers*, or enemy tries to flee), and thus a chance for another 3d10+6 bludgeoning damage is foregone.
2. Benefits: compared to getting access to Barkskin

   - this resource is rechargeable, costs no gold, no consumable items and costs no spell slots.
   - AC versus a given attack can exceed 16 (averages 16.5) - it can sometimes exceed the stated goal, up to AC 20.
3. Reliability: not airtight.

   - On a roll of 1 through 3 it fails to meet the goal of AC 16
   - This isn't an always-on AC boost like choosing the *Armor of Shadows* invocation, per @DarthPseudonym's answer, or the *barkskin* that lasts as long as the polymorph spell lasts: 1 hour.

#### What's useful in this answer?

1. While this may not solve the problem completely, this approach applies assets already under the party's control, and may be a suitable temporary solution until the Warlock hits 9th level and can add the Armor of Shadows invocation for an always-on AC of 15 (per @DarthPseudonym's answer).
2. This {self} answer has the virtue of letting the reader see egg all over
   Korvin's face   The fact that we have a College of Valor bard in the party has been true for over a year (joined when another PC retired) but none of us has ever used "boost your own AC" or "boost your damage" feature from Bardic Inspiration so far; it is usually applied to an attack roll or a saving throw by most of the players.  The answer was *Hiding In Plain Sight*.

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Just checked on roll20 char sheet, the bard's Cha is 20</sub>

Comment: This does use resources already at hand, but I don't think it does so effectively.  The point of the ape is to be a bucket of hp that has damaging attacks.  Using an inspiration to _possibly_ prevent a _single_ hit when the ape is taking multiple hits per round has an awfully high opportunity cost compared to other uses of the ability, like making sure she hits and removes one more enemy from the board.

Comment: @Kirt For the time being, until she gets to level 9 getting Armor of Shadows again is not happening, and the chance to find a tattoo with Barkskin is low to zero, as my DM isn't that well versed in Tasha's stuff.  I disagree that the point is to be a bucket of HP as the Aim of the Polymorph; the spell it lasts for an hour, so we'd like it to be usable in more than one fight. And yes, I do explicitly address the opportunity cost in the answer.

Comment: If you plan on having the ape last the full hour, I don't think preventing a single attack from hitting is going to help as much as taking out an attacker earlier.

Comment: @Kirt Each time one is prevented the Bard can refresh BI .. until he uses up his allotment.  Yeah, a straight 'always on' solution is better, but this is better than nothing.

Comment: Depending on your enemies' +hit modifier, *stacking* this with another AC increase could make it much more effective.  If the chance of out-rolling your AC is already low-ish, then you won't have to spend BI often (especially if you save it for attacks with higher expected damage).  You can also save BI for attack rolls that only beat your AC by 3 or less, instead of gambling on a small chance of preventing damage when you need a high d8 roll, so you're not wasting the bard's bonus actions and BI usages.  (Or if the DM only tells you the *die* roll, you'd have to estimate based on +hit).

Comment: I'd guess that preventing damage to other non-polymorphed PCs is typically worth more to the party overall, so unless other party members have much more valuable reactions than a chance of an op attack, the bard should probably be keeping them topped up with BI for AC boosts if everyone in the party is being targeted by multiple attacks per round, only hitting the ape when everyone else already has unspent BI.